# Am I reading this trace correctly?

Tags: networking, internet, traceroute

We've been having issues at work with getting quotes from UPS today. After having no luck getting to the UPS support page, I decided to traceroute it. The following is the result I got from it:

```
Tracing route to ups.com [153.2.224.50] over a maximum of 30 hops:

1    10 ms     9 ms     9 ms  10.84.224.1
2    10 ms     9 ms    11 ms  gig1-1.shrnpa1-swt401.neo.rr.com [24.164.102.226]
3    11 ms    20 ms    11 ms  tge1-50.yntwoh1-swt402.neo.rr.com [24.164.102.224]
4    11 ms    11 ms    11 ms  tge1-3.yntwoh1-swt401.neo.rr.com [24.164.99.229]
5    10 ms    14 ms    12 ms  tge1-49.yntwoh2-swt401.neo.rr.com [24.164.111.235]
6    14 ms    11 ms    12 ms  tge1-1.alncoh1-swt401.neo.rr.com [24.164.111.237]
7    12 ms    12 ms    13 ms  tge1-1.cntnoh2-swt401.neo.rr.com [24.164.111.239]
8    12 ms    11 ms    11 ms  tge1-6.ncntoh1-swt401.neo.rr.com [24.164.111.241]
9    12 ms    16 ms    12 ms  gig13-0-0.ncntoh1-rtr1.neo.rr.com [24.164.104.89]
10    12 ms    10 ms    17 ms  gig14-0-0.ncntoh1-rtr2.neo.rr.com [24.164.104.170]
11    19 ms    19 ms    31 ms  tge1-0-1.ar01.clevohek.mwrtn.rr.com [65.25.137.237]
12    22 ms    21 ms    23 ms  ae1.tr00.clevohek.mwrtn.rr.com [65.189.140.130]
13    27 ms    32 ms    29 ms  ae-3-0.cr0.dca20.tbone.rr.com [66.109.6.70]
14    28 ms    27 ms    48 ms  107.14.19.135
15    28 ms    28 ms    30 ms  ix-3-2-2-0.tcore2.AEQ-Ashburn.as6453.net [216.6.87.69]
16    27 ms    29 ms    69 ms  192.205.34.249
17    48 ms    53 ms    51 ms  cr1.wswdc.ip.att.net [12.122.220.246]
18    46 ms    51 ms    50 ms  cr2.rlgnc.ip.att.net [12.122.3.169]
19    49 ms    49 ms    47 ms  cr1.rlgnc.ip.att.net [12.122.30.89]
20    44 ms    45 ms    45 ms  cr82.chlnc.ip.att.net [12.123.138.22]
21    47 ms    47 ms    47 ms  12.123.138.141
22    51 ms    53 ms    51 ms  12.249.59.146
23    52 ms    55 ms    55 ms  192.168.112.203
24     *        *        *     Request timed out.
25     *        *        *     Request timed out.
26     *        *        *     Request timed out.
27     *        *        *     Request timed out.
28     *        *        *     Request timed out.
29     *        *        *     Request timed out.
30     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

Obviously, this tells me UPS is unreachable at this moment, but do I read it correctly as saying that we are winding up inside someone's private network (or trying to anyway)? I was under the impression that the 192.168.* range was reserved for private networking. Is this incorrect?

Comment: Mine only took 14 hops to get to the same place you got to at 23. Sounds like some weird configuration here.

Comment: I timed out on the 2nd hop

Comment: 192.168/16 is indeed reserved, but it doesn't prevent hosts from (mistakenly) using private addresses as the *source* of an IP packet.

Comment: Hop count can be different from location to location. At 12.249.59.146 point there is some wrong configuration. My trace route is timeouting at there. 192.168.0.0/16 block is reserverd for private networks. There is no way we can reach it out directly over internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the exact same problem. It is their site. Mine has trouble once it hits 12.249.59.146. Downforeveryoneorjustme: http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/ups.com says that it's everyone.

Comment: I'd completely forgotten about this site. Thanks for reminding me